# Fetch Image From Sqllite Database in iphone

Tags: ios, sqlite, unrecognized-selector

I Want to **save** the image in **Database** and fetch the image in database.i am convert the image in **NSData** and the image is store successfully in database but when i fetch that image from database then it crash.it give this warning

**Warning :- -[__NSCFString bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7916000**

**Below code For save the image in Database**

```
NSData *dataImage1 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image3.image);
 NSString   *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Insert into Gallery(ImageName) VALUES ('%@')",dataImage1];
[Database executeQuery:str];
```

**//Database.m**

```
+(NSString* )getDatabasePath{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Database"];
    return writableDBPath;

}

+(NSMutableArray *)executeQuery:(NSString*)str{

    sqlite3_stmt *statement= nil;
    sqlite3 *database;
    NSString *strPath = [self getDatabasePath];
    NSMutableArray *allDataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    if (sqlite3_open([strPath UTF8String],&database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [str UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {


            while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                            NSInteger i = 0;
                NSInteger iColumnCount = sqlite3_column_count(statement);
                NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
                while (i< iColumnCount) {
                    NSString *str = [self encodedString:(const unsigned char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, i)];


                NSString *strFieldName = [self encodedString:(const unsigned char*)sqlite3_column_name(statement, i)];

                    [dict setObject:str forKey:strFieldName];
                    i++;
                }

                [allDataArray addObject:dict];
                [dict release];
            }
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    } 
    sqlite3_close(database);
    return allDataArray;
}
```

**//Fetch image**

```
NSString *str =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Select * from Gallery where id = 1"];
NSMutableArray *arra =[Database executeQuery:str];
NSData *d =[[arra objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"ImageName"];
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:d];
NSLog(@"%@",img);
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: To insert - Insert sqlite3_bind_blob(stm,2, [image bytes], [image length], NULL);

Comment: to get NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(statement,1) length:sqlite3_column_bytes(statement, 1)];

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you cannot insert binary data by building a SQL statement with a `stringWithFormat`. You're inserting the `NSData` (binary data) into a field called `ImageName`, and you cannot use `stringWithFormat` to build that SQL statement.

Did you really mean to insert the image itself? In that case you'd use SQL like below, with a `?` placeholder, and then use [`sqlite3_bind_blob`](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) for column number `1` with your `NSData` before you call `sqlite3_step`. Thus, the SQL would look like:

```
Insert into Gallery(ImageName) VALUES (?)
```

(As an aside, I'm not a fan of the choice of `ImageName` for the actual data of the image. I'd either use `Image` for the actual image data, or `ImageName` for the name of the image.)

And then, after preparing your SQL, you'd then call:

```
sqlite3_bind_blob(statement, 1, [dataImage1 bytes], [dataImage1 length], SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```

You can then invoke `sqlite3_step`, like normal, to execute the SQL to insert the data.

When retrieving the data, after you successfully `sqlite3_step`, you'd use the appropriate `sqlite3_column_blob` functions:

```
const void *bytes = sqlite3_column_blob(statement, 0);
int len = sqlite3_column_bytes(statement, 0);
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:bytes length:len];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

Having said that, SQLite is notoriously inefficient in storing large blob data. You might want to store the image in the Documents folder and then just store the filename in your `ImageName` field.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are getting bytes in string type in

```
[[arra objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"ImageName"];
```

so first get string and then convert it to data.

try like this:

```
NSData* data = [[[arra objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"ImageName"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: NSString *str =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Select * from Gallery where id = 1"];
    
    NSMutableArray *arra =[Database executeQuery:str];
    
    NSData* data = [[[arra objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"ImageName"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 
    

    
    UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
    
    
    NSLog(@"%@",img);

Comment: what your ImageName contains?? i think you have saved nsdata in string . so we need to get data in string and then convert it to nsdata. so above code should work. show me your data.

Comment: You cannot just take binary `NSData`, throw it into a `NSString`, and then insert that into a SQL statement with `stringWithFormat`. There are tons of problems with that approach.