# how to update the image in sqlite using ios

Tags: ios, sqlite

i want to store data with an image using this query,everything update correctly but the image column is always null.i don't know what is wrong in this query.please anybody help me fix it out.i'm new to iOS and sqlite too.

```
    UIImage *uiimg = img.image;
    NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(uiimg);

    NSString *cmd = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"update APPUSERS set name = '%@', u_name =           '%@', contact_no = '%@', address = '%@', dob = '%@', pswrd = '%@', confirm_pswrd = '%@', img = '%d' where u_name ='%@'",name.text, uname.text, pnoneno.text, address.text, dob.text, password.text, confirmpassword.text, data, tempstore] ;

    const char * sql = [cmd UTF8String];


    if (sqlite3_step(update_statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
     {
            NSLog(@"success");
     }
       else
     {
            NSLog(@"failed");

    }
```

Comment: while doing the sqlite3_bind_text for all fields the data not get update.that why i using this method to save data and image too.

Comment: i'm getting issue while update,not in insert..

Comment: @user2315316 It doesn't matter. You should always do `sqlite3_bind_xxx`, whether, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or even just a `WHERE` clause in a `SELECT` statement. If it wasn't working with `sqlite3_bind_xxx` before, you probably didn't look at `sqlite3_errmsg` to identify the source of the problem and remedy it. Note, if any of these values could be `nil`, you'd also want to check for that condition, and use `sqlite3_bind_null` in that case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/17994313/1271826 for an example of how to use `sqlite3_bind_blob` to store your `NSData` in the database.

Furthermore, you absolutely should avoid using `stringWithFormat` for building SQL statements in general. What if the address was `123 O'Brian Way` or `Martha's Vineyard`? That apostrophe would prematurely terminate the string you're inserting. Double quotes are no better, when you go to insert `Jimmy "The Greek" Snyder` or `Dwayne "The Rock" Johnson`. Worse, a malevolent user could wreak havoc with SQL injection.

You should use `?` placeholders and `sqlite3_bind_blob` function for `NSData`. And for your strings, use `sqlite3_bind_text`.

Thus:

```
UIImage *uiimg = img.image;
NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(uiimg);

const char *sql = "update APPUSERS set name = ?, u_name = ?, contact_no = ?, address = ?, dob = ?, pswrd = ?, confirm_pswrd = ?, img = ? where u_name =?";

if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &update_statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    NSLog(@"prepare failed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

if (sqlite3_bind_text(update_statement, 1, [name.text UTF8String], -1, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    NSLog(@"bind 1 failed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

if (sqlite3_bind_text(update_statement, 2, [uname.text UTF8String], -1, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    NSLog(@"bind 2 failed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

if (sqlite3_bind_text(update_statement, 3, [pnoneno.text UTF8String], -1, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    NSLog(@"bind 3 failed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

if (sqlite3_bind_text(update_statement, 4, [address.text UTF8String], -1, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    NSLog(@"bind 4 failed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

if (sqlite3_bind_text(update_statement, 5, [dob.text UTF8String], -1, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    NSLog(@"bind 5 failed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

if (sqlite3_bind_text(update_statement, 6, [password.text UTF8String], -1, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    NSLog(@"bind 6 failed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

if (sqlite3_bind_text(update_statement, 7, [confirmpassword.text UTF8String], -1, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    NSLog(@"bind 7 failed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

// note, use blob here

if (sqlite3_bind_blob(update_statement, 8, [data bytes], [data length], SQLITE_TRANSIENT) != SQLITE_OK)
    NSLog(@"bind 8 failed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

if (sqlite3_bind_text(update_statement, 9, [tempstore UTF8String], -1, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    NSLog(@"bind 9 failed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

if (sqlite3_step(update_statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
{
    NSLog(@"success");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"failed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}

sqlite3_finalize(update_statement);
```

Note, in addition to doing `sqlite3_bind_xxx`, I'd also suggest (a) don't forget to do `sqlite3_prepare_v2` first; (b) on *any* error, look at `sqlite3_errmsg`; and (c) remember to do `sqlite3_finalize` at the end to free up your memory.

Note, though, SQLite is notably inefficient in storing large blobs. If the images are small thumbnails it's not an issue, but for large images, you should be saving the image to your `Documents` folder and then only saving the file path in your database.

Finally, note that if you had an image that you loaded into a `UIImage` that you then re-retrieved via `UIImagePNGRepresentation`, that can result in data loss or the file may get considerably larger. It depends upon the original source of the image. People often assume if they do `UIImagePNGRepresentation`, they're guaranteed to get the same image, and while it may look virtually identical, it can be altered in the process (not always; it depends). If you have access to the original asset/file/`NSData` you used to set the `UIImage`, you should just refer back to that.

---

As an unrelated aside, you really shouldn't be storing passwords in plaintext in your database, either. You should encrypt them or use a [keychain](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html) to store the passwords.

Answer (score 1):

Try to save Image name in the database and image in Documents folder by creating NSDocument in NSFileManager.These are singleton instances.You can save the image in phone memory folder which is related to documents of the applciation

example you can find in this path [Read/write file in Documents directory problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6496454/read-write-file-in-documents-directory-problem)